# AngularFire: How to update a $firebaseArray by extending the service and using the $$updated private method

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, denormalized

I have two separate lists of Posts and Authors in my database, each Post containing an authorId to refer to the corresponding author.

The following method helps me retrieve the whole list of Posts by systematically including the name of the author for each Post:

```
app.factory('NormalizedPosts', function($firebaseArray, FirebaseFactory) {
    var PostsWithAuthors = $firebaseArray.$extend({

        // override $$added to include author name
        $$added: function(snap) {
            var record = $firebaseArray.prototype.$$added.call(this, snap);

            FirebaseFactory.$getAuthorId( record.authorId ).$loaded(function( authorData ) {
                record.authorData = authorData;
            });

            return record;
        },

        // ????????
        $$updated: function(snap) { 

            var rec = $firebaseArray.prototype.$$updated.call(this, snap); 
            var updatedRecord = this.$getRecord(snap.key()); 

            FirebaseFactory.$getAuthorId( updatedRecord.authorId )
            .$loaded(function( authorData ) { 
                rec.authorData = authorData; 
            }); 

        return rec; 

        }

    });

    return PostsWithAuthors;
});
```

PS: The FirebaseFactory is just a wrapper for firebase methods.

I then call

```
var list = new NormalizedPosts ( new Firebase(FBURL).child("posts") );
```

in my controller to get the full list. This works great.

I'm scratching my head with what should go into the $$updated method: When a new Post is added, the list gets updated as expected (through the $$added method). But when there's a change in a Post data (e.g. the post title), my list does not get updated, as I'm currently returning false in the $$updated method.

Question: What should go in the $$updated method so that when theres a change in a Post data, my list gets updated accordingly (and further returns the author's name!). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going through too many loops to get something simple done.

If the name of the author is "part of" the article than you should save it:

```
{
    "articles": {
        "firebase-uniq-id-1": {
            "title": "My Writing Process",
            "published": "2016-01-01",
            "author": {
                "firebase-uniq-id-2": "Ernest Hemingway"
            }
        }
    },
    "authors": {
        "firebase-uniq-id-2": {
            "name": "Ernest Hemingway",
            "born": "1899-07-21",
            "whatever": "Some Data"
        }
    }
}
```

When you'll want to show other details about the author, fetch it.

Edit:
If you still wish to use the extension option, I believe the only thing you're missing there is extending the `updateRecord` with `rec`:

```
FirebaseFactory.$getAuthorId( updatedRecord.authorId )
    .$loaded(function( authorData ) { 
        updatedRecord.authorData = authorData; 
        angular.extend(updatedRecord, snap.val());
    });
```

Also, in `$$updated` you need to return a boolean saying if the record changed or not, and not the record itself.

Keep in mind that if you go that path you shouldn't use the default `$save()` method of `$firebaseArray` since it will also save the full authorData

Comment: Thanks Idan. The case I described above is indeed a simple case and your approach works well to retrieve the name of the author. In practice I need to fetch all sort of data  (publishing company, sales data, etc ... in the same query. So would you suggest to systematically duplicate the required data in the articles node for all the data I need (with the same approach you used in your example) Or would you take my approach to extend the service, and in this case, as per my original question,how can I make sure that data will be updated through the extended service ?

Comment: It depends how rich the data is. AFAIK this is the approach for JSON based DBs. You have the index and selected data as the value of the index. If you still need the extension, I think there are some good examples in AngularFire's docs that can help

Comment: Thanks Idan. No example with AngularFire's docs I'm afraid. And the only relevant I found does not address the $$updated issue I am facing: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/f78d4a224c06a643ddfa

Comment: What about 
    `$$updated: function(snap) {
        // this is the $firebaseArray instance so you can use it instead of $firebaseArray.prototype
        var updatedRecord = this.$getRecord(snap.key());
        FirebaseFactory.$getAuthorId( updatedRecord.authorId ).$loaded(function( authorData ) {
            updatedRecord.authorData = authorData;
        });
        // You could return false if it's not modified, just returning this for simplicity
        return !!updatedRecord;
    }`

Comment: Idan thanks for the follow-up; it does the trick and the updatedRecord with the author is returned; the issue however is that 'var updatedRecord = this.$getRecord(snap.key())' does fetch the old data, so if something is updated on the record itself, e.g. the article title, it does not return the new title; any idea?

Comment: Ok, so just call the "super" `$$updated` also, like you did for `$$added` method, or just update yourself using `snap.val()` as the new data

Comment: I  do not quite follow your option 2) // as option 1) is concerned, we're back to my original question: $$updated: function(snap) { var rec = $firebaseArray.prototype.$$updated.call(this, snap); var updatedRecord = this.$getRecord(snap.key()); FirebaseFactory.$getAuthorId( updatedRecord.authorId ).$loaded(function( authorData ) { rec.authorData = authorData; }); return rec } // does update the article title if there's a change,, but does not add the authorData. Any idea?

Comment: please note that I update rec in my suggestion as I user the super $$updated method; please also note that I call  var rec = $firebaseArray.prototype.$$updated.call(this, snap) and not  var rec = $firebaseObject.prototype.$$updated.call(this, snap) as I extend the $firebaseArray (although I haven't found any single example that does just that)

Comment: It's getting harder to understand the full picture here. Can you update the code in your question with what you currently have for `$$updated`?

Comment: Idan, not quite as the updatedRecord still fetch data from the existing $firebaseArray so if something is updated there (e.g. article title), the output will not reflect the change. That being said, your idea/ comments helped me solved it - see my answer below - so thanks so much for your help on this !

Comment: Happy to help :) edited again, because I still believe you already have the updated entity in `snap.val()` so it saves you waiting for one of the `$loaded()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$$updated: function(snap) { 

    // boolean for the $$updated method
    var rec = $firebaseArray.prototype.$$updated.call(this, snap); 

    // existing record as per this
    var existingRecord = this.$getRecord(snap.key()); 

    // record as per FB database
    var updatedRecord = snap.val();

    if ( rec ) {

        FirebaseFactory.$getAuthorId( updatedRecord.authorId )
        .$loaded(function( authorData ) { 
            updatedRecord.authorData = authorData;
            angular.extend(existingRecord, updatedRecord);
        }); 

    } // end if loop

    return rec; 

}
```